# Indeterminate Limit

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Could someone help me?
I have to calculate this with polar coordinates.

My original function was:

$\lim _{\left(x,y\right)\to \left(0,0\right)}\frac{e^{\left(\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}\right)}}{sen\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}$

And after I use polar coordinates I got this:

$\lim \:_{r\to \:0}\left(\frac{e^{\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right)}}{sen\left(r\right)}\right)$

$\lim \:_{r\to \:0}\left(\frac{1}{e^{\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)}sen\left(r\right)}\right)$

Since this is not an indeterminate $\frac{0}{0}$ I can't use the L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: What is your $sen(r)$?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it.

Comment: @Bach I think it is sine in a different language (e.g., "seno" in Spanish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the well-known limit $\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\sin r}{r} = 1$, we have

$$\lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{e^{-1/r^2}}{\sin r} = \lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{e^{-1/r^2}}{r}
= \lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{z}{e^{z^2}}$$
from which it is simple to use L'Hôpital's rule to conclude.

Comment: Thank you for the insite. Since I have $\lim _{z\to 0}\left(\frac{z}{e^{z^2}}\right)$ I will got $ 0 $ and don't need L'Hôpital's rule or I will need?

Comment: @CarlosHenrique Note that the limit is $z \to \infty$, not $z \to 0$. This is due to the change of variables $z=1/r$.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but in the second step how you get  $\lim _{r\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{\left(\frac{-1}{r^2}\right)}}{r}\right)$

Comment: @CarlosHenrique I multiply by $\frac{\sin r}{r}$ whose limit is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Just erase your last step...

$$
\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/r^2}}{\sin r}
$$

is already a $\frac 00$ indetermination.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\frac{e^{\left(\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}\right)}}{\sin\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}=\frac{e^{\left(\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}\right)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sin\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)} \to 0\cdot 1 =0$$

indeed by ${x^2+y^2}=r^2\to 0$

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sin\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}=\frac r {\sin r}\to 1$$

and by $\frac1{x^2+y^2}=t^2\to \infty$

$$\frac{e^{\left(\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}\right)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=te^{-t^2}=\frac t{ e^{t^2}}\to 0$$